# PNGs appearing as black tiles in Media Section in Umbraco

Tags: javascript, angular, umbraco, umbraco7

when we try to use the png images inside the RTE in umbraco the Png images showing as black tiles the server is Azure any one experienced like this ? Umbraco 7.15.3 with latest upgrade

I have found a similar link in forum but no answer so far https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/99474-pngs-appearing-as-black-tiles-in-media-section
[image]

and the PostProcessor `<package id="ImageProcessor.Web.PostProcessor" version="1.4.0.100" targetFramework="net462" />`

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in `ImageProcessor.Web.PostProcessor` on Azure that is currently being worked on. See [this issue on Github](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/747)

For now, the best "fix" is to uninstall `ImageProcessor.Web.PostProcessor`.

Comment: Hi @jason, Yeah i have noticed that is the only solution from forum , but i am looking out any other solutions or findings , any how thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @GayathriMohan best update your question to make that clear then. Either way, you will need to uninstall that package before you try any other fix.